# Dynamic form fields validation under MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I know that this code works just fine to validate field.

```
<%: Html.TextBox("FirstName", ViewData["FirstName"], new { maxlength = 200 })%> 
<%: Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName", "*")%>
```

And I guess that possible that dynamic generated name of the control to validate should work as well. But it does't.

```
 <% for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGuests; i++)
 { %>                     

 First Name:  <%:  Html.TextBox("FirstName_" + i) %> 
 <%: Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName_" + i, "*") %>  

 <% } %>
```

So at this case no validation at all. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the validation logic for that. without implementing a validation, Html.ValidationMessage() method is no use at all.

Comment: Yeah... I know that I can use code behind for that. I just guessed that this should work Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName_" + i, "*") but thanks anyway!